# jquery background-position-y to be triggered when has a relative class

Tags: jquery, background-position

Considering that in firefox the position-y doesn't work I need to write a bit of code in jquery to be able to set the background-position-y when hasClass 'no-event'.

what I am doing wrong?

**CSS**

```
#products-events .nav li.no-event a:after{background-position-y:-67px;}
```

**Jquery**

```
    if ($('#products-events li').hasClass('no-event')) {

        //$('.no-event').css('background-position','-67' + yposition );
    }
```

FIDDLE

http://jsfiddle.net/L8qvz/58/

Comment: Can you post your example if jsfiddle?

Comment: i updated my answer, check it out please

Comment: I'm trying to put it on fiddle

Comment: did you solve it? im gonna delete my answer..